# Problems with UI Button Settings & Locations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, location, pixel

I have custom buttons which I need to be placed in certain areas when I setup them up via a template i have on PS they look pixel perfect but the when I run it it looks like crap. I have the right sizes and the right x,y coordinates set up in the attributes section? is there any way to not have a status bar at all or some way to get pixel perfect measurements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
btnObje.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,image.frame.size.width,image.frame.size.height);
```